# How to calculate GM% with multiple sales on the same date into unique dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm given gm%, gm&, sales, sales cost, and several of the same dates. For every date, I want to find the total Gross Margin Percentage for that day. How can I do that in Excel? I want my output to list a unique date and the GM% corresponding to the date.

Comment: `SUMIF/COUNTIF` Using ADO and SQL, or maybe a pivot?

Comment: A pivot table seems the most reasonable, but the dates keep repeating. How do I get it to show unique dates?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav this is where my merchandise planning background kicks in and says "hell no". Averaging GM% (or any % figure for that matter) yields no meaningful figure whatsoever.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon that wasn't the question i answered, it was edited since i answered it.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav not the question I answered either. Isn't this fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can't average gross margin percentages and get an accurate figure. You need the total cost and total retail (/selling price) amounts, and with the total cost and retail amounts you'll be able to calculate the average gross margin percentage with `1-Sum([Cost])/Sum([Retail])`.

Averaging percentages is not accurate reporting. Proof:

```
Units    Cost    Retail    GM%
10       379     1000      62.1%
 1       327      650      49.7%
```

The "average" GM% you would be aggregating would be 55.9%...
**but the correct GM% would be 57.2%**.

If all you have is the total sales amount and the GM%, you need to compute the total cost:

```
[Cost$] = [GM%]*[Retail$]
```

If all you have is the total cost amount and the GM%, you need to compute the total retail:

```
[Retail$] = [Cost$]/(1-[GM%])
```

If you have the GM$ amount *and* the GM%, you can calculate both cost and retail amounts:

```
[GM%] = [GM$]/[Retail$]
[GM$] = [Retail$]-[Cost$]
```

```
[Retail$] = 1/[GM%]*[GM$]
[Cost$] = 1/[GM%]*[GM$]*(1-[GM%])
```

With these, you can now accurately compute the average GM% figure.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. I have the Gross Margin (not Gross Margin Percentage). I'll still need to calculate the average gross margin for the day. I wish I could do this manually for every day but there's a years worth of data.

Comment: @J.Siu you can't do it without the total retail$ amount (you can compute the total cost$ amount from the GM% given total retail$)

Comment: @J.Siu wait hold on - you say you have the GM$ figure? If you have both the GM$ and GM%, you're all set (see edit)

Comment: @J.Siu once you have the `Cost$` and `Retail$` amounts in your data source, make a pivot table and add a calculated field for the `GM%`, `=1-[Cost$]/[Retail$]`. The aggregated figures will then be accurate.

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu. I don’t have the retail$ figures, but rather sales and sales cost. So that’s sales$, sales cost$, GM$, and GM% that I have.

Comment: Then you have everything you need........ substitute "Retail$" for "Sales$" and "Cost$" for "SalesCost$", discard the GM% - compute it in the pivot table instead. Note how your original question states none of this critical information.

Comment: Haha, Ok. I just wanted to make sure retail == sales for this scenario. Thanks a bunch.